# Ambiguous reference and namespace (clash of definitions from the two external libraries)

Tags: c++, oop, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I experience the collapse of definitions i can't make sense of.

Schematically the problem is as follows:

The main project file has two includes:

```
include <lib1.h>
include <lib2.h>
```

The first header includes couple of other headers from the library, in one of those there is a direct (not covered with a name-space) definition:

```
template<typename T> class SparseMatrix;
```

The lib2.h has the following inside

```
namespace lib2
{
   using namespace lib3;

   class ...
   {
      ...
      SparseMatrix<double> ...
      ...
    }
}
```

Inside lib3, covered with the namespace, there is also a definition of SparseMatrix class.

Each library separately compiles with no problem. When I try to compile the executable which uses the, compiler produces an error:

```
lib2.h:70:7: error: reference to 'SparseMatrix' is ambiguous
```

Which looks strange to me since nowhere in the main program do I write

```
using namespace lib3;
```

Thus I see no reason why those definitions should collapse.
I would greatly appreciate any possible explanation for the problem.

Of course, I can enclose the definitions from the lib1 into a their own namespace, but then I would need to modify quite a number of files there, which I would rather not do.

COMMENT:
the answer below is correct but i was also able to get around the problem by changing the order of included files, i.e. first include lib2 and then lib1.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> nowhere in the main program do i write `using namespace lib3;`

But if you look in `lib2.h`, exactly that has been written. The contents of the `lib3` namespace have been brought into `lib2` and are now visible when defining the `SparseMatrix<double>` object.

You can think of `lib2.h` as being something like this after all includes have been resolved:

```
template <typename T> class SparseMatrix;    // (1)

namespace lib3
{
   template <typename T> class SparseMatrix; // (2)
}

namespace lib2
{
   using namespace lib3; // (3)

   class ...
   {
      ...
      SparseMatrix<double> ... // (4)
      // ::SparseMatrix<double> would only see (1)
      // lib2::SparseMatrix<double> would only see (2)
    }
}
```

The line marked (1) declares `SparseMatrix` which is immediately visible on line (4). The declaration on line (2) would not be, but since line (3) brings it into namespace `lib2`, it is now also visible on line (4).

You can get around this simply by fully qualifying the type:

```
::SparseMatrix<double> ...
```

`::` with no preceding namespace denotes the global namespace.

The other alternative is to not have `using namespace lib3;` in `lib2.h` and properly qualify the contents of the `lib3` namespace.

Comment: well, but this is covered in its own namespace "namespace lib2", should not this help? I actually though that this "using namespace lib3" is relevant only within the lib2, and not outside of the library which will later include it.

Comment: @Denis But the class containing the `SparseMatrix<double>` is inside the `lib2` namespace. So of course it is affected by that `using namespace lib3` which is also inside `lib2`.

Comment: But you reference `SparseMatrix` within the lib2 namespace, so you might want to have `lib2::SparseMatrix` or `::SparseMatrix`. Both can be referenced by writing `SparseMatrix`. Thus the `::` to say "I want the global one".

Comment: @sftrabbit sorry, i must be misunderstanding something, but i do neither "using namespace lib2" within the main program. So it should stay within its namespace and i used it like lib2::ObjectFoo...

Comment: @Denis Look at my edit. I've annotated the code and described why there are two definitions of `SparseMatrix` visible in the class.

Comment: @sftrabbit i see now, do you think one can get around this if i change the order of includes? That is, include lib2 before lib1 and therefore the SparseMatrix<double> should not be available at point (4) ?

Comment: @Denis Order of includes makes no difference. I would worry more about why you are doing `using namespace lib3;` in the `lib2` namespace. It's quite a big thing to bring an entire namespace's contents into another namespace.

Comment: @sftrabbit sorry for keep bothering, but do you think i can keep "namespace lib2 { using namespace lib3;...}" in sources? oddly enough after i edited the header compiler does not find the implementation of constructor.

Comment: @Denis It's hard for me to say without knowing exactly what you're doing. Just think about what should be in which namespaces. Design it properly.